# How To Print Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Label On DVD?

Tags: system-installation, printing, dvd

My google fu must be weak, or I am missing the key search terms, since I imagine many people would be interested in direct printing labels on their iso install DVDs.   Does anyone know where I can find Ubuntu & Lubuntu 18.04 LTS Label images to print on my ISO DVDs?  I would like my install disks to look more professional than typical permanent marker scrawling on disk.

Is there any Chromebook apps to print these image using Google Cloudprint  to my Epson XP-830 printer?  My Epson XP-830 has built in DVD printing capaility, complete with DVD tray!

Thank You,
ABQ :)

Comment: I don't know if there is an oficial one, but you can find a couple of them searching in Google Images: https://images.google.com/?q=ubuntu+18.04+dvd

Comment: Turboprint provides this support http://www.turboprint.info/printer_Epson_XP830series.html as a specialist driver; do you use the generic Epson driver at present?